# What is the proper way to use a .NET DataSet?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to use .NET DataSets. Are you supposed to create a DataTable for every table in your database and create relationships in the DataSet? It seems crazy to me to reconstruct your entire database structure in the DataSet.

I'll use a simplified example of my database.
Lets say I have a `CompanyEquipment` table. Each piece of equipment belongs to a cost center, and the cost center data is stored in the `CostCenter` table and is related to the `CompanyEquipment` table. Lets say I have a stored procedure that returns `CompanyEquipment` data already joined with the `CostCenter` table to return all the info in one query. I could use the stored procedure to populate a `DataTable`, but how would this de-normalized result table be saved back to the database? I don't know if this is a good way to do it. Querying many-to-many relationships that make use of association (bridge) tables would require multiple queries anyway I think. For example, I have an `EquipmentRole` table, that stores different equipment usages, and an `EquipmentRoleAssignment` table where multiple roles can be assigned to pieces of equipment.

Alternatively, if I have DataTables that mimic the database, I would have to query each table separately using DataAdapter.Fill() on each table to put the related data in each `DataTable`. So I would have something like `select * from CompanyEquipment where equipID = 1234` and I would use that with an adapter to fill a `CompanyEquipment DataTable`, and then I would have to use another query `select * from CostCenter where costCenterID = <costcenterID from the companyequipment record>` and fill the `CostCenter DataTable`. With this approach I have to hit the database twice, and I lose the power of the DBMS to perform joins.

I'm new to data driven applications, so I'm not familiar with the workflow; especially how many times I should hit the database to get one representation of data. Any help is appreciated. I'm working in C#.

Comment: It may be a good idea to start by creating some classes to represent your data as you would prefer to work with it in your application.  Relying on DataTable and DataSet really locks you into your database's structure and you end up losing flexibility.  Also, certain built-in structures (DataSet in particular) pose additional problems when it comes to tasks involving serialization and/or caching.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I actually started building my own classes to represent the data in an object-oriented way. I even started building my own mapping classes, and then ran into problems like mapping many-to-many relationships as a list of one domain type inside of another domain type, and handling nulls. Persisting these objects brought on a host of other design issues, and then I realized I was building an ORM by myself which is stupid because I'll never get this application working in the next century.

Comment: Can be converted to a community wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used Datasets in the past (way long ago though)  and this is my 0.02$ based on my experience

Both your option 1 as well as Option 2 are valid scenarios as to how datasets could be used.

**For Retrieval Scenarios :-**
It depends on how you are using the data.

For example, in a scenario where you know that all the main table + related table data is being for eg displayed to the user immediately, option 1 is probably preferable.

However, in a scenario, where you might show a table with main table data and only on click of a row, show the related table information, it might be preferable to go with option 2 instead as it allows you to get the data as requested.

**For Insert / Update Scenarios**

Option 2 works best in such scenarios as your in-memory structure mimics your database. So, using an adapter or even the commandbuilder objects and the datarow state (Inserted / Updated / Deleted), you could easily insert / update / delete the appropriate data without too much hassle. If you were to use Option 1, you will need to write the logic to split it up and save into the separate tables yourself.

Hope this is useful. However, like most real life scenarios, it really depends

**Note:** I totally avoid datasets / datatables and i have for a while due to them being quite heavy objects and hence tend to be a bit of a drain on resources. If you do use them, make sure you test for performance - based on your performance requirements to ensure that they dont end up being unsuitable in the long term

Comment: Thanks for your input. At least I know I wasn't too far off. DataSet wasn't my first choice, I wanted to use entity framework but ran into some issues and time constraints are killing my options. I have minimal experience with DataSet and no experience with EF. So I thought I would use DataSet, but I've never used DataSet on a project this big. For the record, if using option 2, would it be normal to create DataTables for every database table even if it was 30 tables? Also, what do you use in place of DataSets/Tables, because like you said DataSet may not be the best option for the future.

Comment: Yes. If you were going the datatables route, i would strongly advise using "Strongly Typed" datasets / datatables hence a different one would exist for each table. It just makes things a while lot easier both to code and to maintain. I believe there are tools available out there that will just auto - generate the xsd / code for your datatables if u point them to your db. To your 2nd point, I mostly use POCO's for most of my applications. In terms of DAL, i have used a variety of techniques from ORM's like nHibernate / Auto Generating DAL code using CodeSmith templates / handwriting the DAL

Comment: In my experience, using an ORM always can be a bit overkill at times when you are making something simplistic and conversely, sometimes it can be a pain especially if your object graphs are very big and complex. So, I dont have a silver bullet for that part. I do whatever makes sense best for that situation / project

Comment: @reallythecrash: If you want to get started quickly with EF4, then work database upwards. Generate your EF model from the database - then it should be as simple as adding a reference to the context (database) and some very simple methods for reading/writing.  Personally, I prefer code-first POCO but end up uwing database first more often simply because I often have the database already in place.

Answer (score 6):

Not at all? I have not been using DataSets since .NET 1.0. Use an ORM, game over. DataSets have zero real use outside of reporting applications that let the user put together their queries fully dynamically, and even in that situation there are better solutions most of the time.

Comment: You don't way what version of .Net you are using, but look at "Entity Framework" and you should be heading in the right direction.

Comment: I looked into EF, but ran into an issue with inheritance. The database mixes table-per-hierarchy and table-per-type inheritance, and EF does not support mixing inheritance schemes. So, lets say all equipment inherits from a base entity Item that should be abstract, I had to make it non-abstract and query for types as the base type while they should be strongly-type subtypes. For example, if I query for a Computer, and Computer does not have a subtype entity I would receive objects of type Item. If that sounds correct to you, then maybe I should just use EF? It seemed strange to me.

Comment: @BlueChippy Sorry. Using .Net 4. Thanks for your recommendation. Please take a look at my response to TomTom about the issue I had with EF. Maybe I could get your opinion on that. Let me know if you need more info on the problem.

Comment: not ever been using EF - would start now possibly with 4.5 if I would need state tracking. I do most work with BlToolkit, but our work is kind of special - we use the database as serialization store, all transactions happen in memory. Well, 90% of them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using POCO with Entity Framework. With EF, you can use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/) which generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database. That would reduce your effort in creating classes yourselves. You have now classes which you can use with EF to address problems you described in your question.